# Getting permission denied on Android M

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions

I'm getting PERMISSION_DENIED for WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE that is in fact active:

[image]

I'm using a library called Permiso to retrieve them:

```
private void attemptStartImagePicker() {
    Permiso.getInstance().requestPermissions(new Permiso.IOnPermissionResult() {
        @Override
        public void onPermissionResult(Permiso.ResultSet resultSet) {
            if (!resultSet.isPermissionGranted(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) || !resultSet.isPermissionGranted(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                showErrorDialog(getString(R.string.change_profile_image_permission_denied));
            } else {
                startImagePicker();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onRationaleRequested(final Permiso.IOnRationaleProvided callback, String... permissions) {
            Permiso.getInstance().showRationaleInDialog(getString(R.string.grant_access), getString(R.string.change_profile_image_rationale), null, new Permiso.IOnRationaleProvided() {
                @Override
                public void onRationaleProvided() {
                    callback.onRationaleProvided();
                }
            });
        }
    }, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
}
```

I've also tried with the code from the documentation:

```
private void requestWritePermission() {
    // Here, thisActivity is the current activity
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL);
            // PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL is an
            // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
            // result of the request.
    } else {
        startImagePicker();
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // permission was granted
                startImagePicker();
            } else {
                // permission denied
                showErrorDialog(getString(R.string.change_profile_image_permission_denied));
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

**In both cases I'm getting that READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is enabled, but WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is not!**

Relevant part of manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.nothereal.packagename"
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="23"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
```

Relevant part of gradle:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
}

dependencies {    
        compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.3'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:24.1.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.3'
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.3'
        compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.3'
```

Testing on a Nexus 5X Android Version 6.0.1

Comment: Could you post error log?

Comment: Just a quick note - if you ask for Write Permission, you don't need Read Permission.

Comment: Thanks @slanecek , I've just tried removing the read permission, and at least on the device I mentioned, it doesn't even show a requested permission in the app settings!

Comment: @FelixEdelmann there's no error log, it just keeps returning PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED. No exception or error.

Comment: I would suggest you use this library for permission-handling: https://github.com/hotchemi/PermissionsDispatcher

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was due to having more than one module with a Manifest: I had the permission in my app module manifest, and another module had it too.

Removing it from the other module did the trick.